# Hydrostatic pressure of helium gas in a closed volume below 4K

Tags: thermodynamics, cryogenics

I have filled a tight container of a fixed volume with natural helium gas (helium 4) and a sample at room temperature and atmospheric pressure. Now I cool the container down to temperatures between 50mK and 4K. What is the most accurate way to compute the hydrostatic pressure exerted onto the sample by the helium gas for the given temperature range? I tried a maxwell construction using the Van-der-Waals equation but I seem to get inaccurate results compared to my experiment.  [image: Results from VdW with maxwell construction]

Comment: Please show us more details of what you did.

Comment: Try using the NIST Webbook for helium thermophysical properties https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/fluid/. Use isochoric process starting at room temperature and pressure. This will atleast give you P vs T down to the lambda point of 2.17 K. Below this, a fair approximation can be done using ideal gas law because helium will have very low pressure. Just make sure you are not crossing the saturation curve for helium. Otherwise some of the helium will have condensed and ideal gas law will not give accurate P vs T values.